# I don't see output of component in React App

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react, I made a simple component and render some data into this component but I don't see any output on the browser and I am getting this error on the console "react_dom_client__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.render is not a function".

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
// import App from './App';
// import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import Counter from './components/counter';

ReactDOM.render(<Counter />, document.getElementById("root"));
// registerServiceWorker();
```

counter.jsx

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class Counter extends Component {
    state = {
        count : 1,
    }
    render() {
        return (
        <div>
            <span>{this.formatCount()}</span>
        </div>
        );
    }

    formatCount() {
        const {count} = this.state;
        return count === 0 ? 'Zero' : count;
    }
}

export default Counter;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a root and then render with it:

```js
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<Counter />);
```

Answer (score 1):

Few things are missing on your Counter class component, see below:

```
class Counter extends Component {
   // You need to call the Component constructor so the class Counter inherit 
   // the React Component properties and methods
   constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     // You need to add the state to 'this' so you can reference it later
     this.state = {
       count: 1
     };
   }
  
  // Create the function before you call it, that is why I move
  // it at the top of the render
  formatCount() {
    const {count} = this.state;
    return count === 0 ? 'Zero' : count;
  }
  
  render() {
     return (
     <div>
        <span>{this.formatCount()}</span>
     </div>);
  }
}

// This is fine as long as you have a div with id of root
ReactDOM.render(<Counter />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import Counter from './components/counter';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Counter />
  </React.StrictMode>);
```

**React.StrictMode** is a tool for highlighting potential problems in an application, StrictMode does not render any visible UI. It activates additional checks and warnings for its descendants. see https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html for more information.

Answer (score 0):

In your `index.js` file you need to update the code according to `react18` version for that you need to create root and then render it.

```
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';

const container = document.getElementById('root');
const root = createRoot(container); 
root.render(<Counter />);
```